# Eagle Board Editor: Garbage or stray marks of a particular component stays back even after moving it

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am designing a primitive PCB design in Eagle. I used many tools like move, route, delete, smash, etc. I dont know why I bumped into this problem. When i move a component ,there is a part of the component(like wire frame) staying back , but the full component is movable.
I assumed it may be a bug(where eagle is not refreshing the screen) but when i checked for errors, these stray marks we mentioned in the error's list. Please help me with this.

Comment: Eagle often has problems with refreshing the screen, but your problem is strange. Could you add a screen shot?

Comment: Listed as what kind of error?

Comment: Please post a screenshot, otherwise we can't envision the discrepancy that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run a DRC recently?

If there were errors shown by the DRC, they will remain as sort of cross-hatched lines when you move the object that caused the error.

Notice how in this screenshot I added a wire to create some intentional DRC errors, but even after I move the wire out of the way, the errors remain marked. Once you run DRC again they will go away. The same is true for components if for example there were Stop Mask errors, you can end up with lines around where the component used to be.

The solution as I say is to run the DRC check again after moving the object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, the solution I found was actually saving my work, closing the program, and the opening up eagle again. The trace left was gone as well as the error in ERC. Have you tried doing this?